# problem with histograms from grouped data in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a data like this:

```
    marital-status      age
0   Never-married       25
1   Married-civ-spouse  38
2   Married-civ-spouse  28
3   Married-civ-spouse  44
4   Never-married       18
5   Never-married       34
6   Never-married       29
7   Married-civ-spouse  63
8   Never-married       24
9   Married-civ-spouse  55
10  Married-civ-spouse  65
11  Married-civ-spouse  36
12  Never-married       26
13  Married-civ-spouse  58
14  Married-civ-spouse  48
15  Married-civ-spouse  43
16  Never-married       20
17  Married-civ-spouse  43
18  Widowed             37
19  Married-civ-spouse  40
20  Married-civ-spouse  34
21  Never-married       34
22  Divorced            72
23  Never-married       25
24  Married-civ-spouse  25
```

I want to plot histogram of ages for every category in martial-status column. I've tried this:

```
df['marital-status'].hist(by=df['age']);
```

But the result is not readable at all[image: result]:

How can I make it readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe swapping `age` and `marital-status` in your command:

```
df['age'].hist(by=df['marital-status']);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's right! but it's still not good enough. is there a way so i can make it biger? i've tried plt.figure(figsize=(16,6)) but it didn't work!

Comment: Pass `figsize=(16,6)` directly: `hist(by=df['marital-status'], figsize=(16,6))`.